# Shader graph for UI works in scene tab but not in game tab

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, unity3d-ui

I'm trying to create a shader that would add a glow to a UI item. It works in scene tab:

[image: shader works]

But in Game tab or in built project in doesn't work at all:

[image: shader doesn't work]

I'm not really good at shaders so I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or Shader Graph doesn't supposed to be used with Unity UI. Does it?

Comment: What render mode is it set to?

Comment: @Ruzihm Lightweight RP

Comment: But HDRP didn't make any difference

Comment: I mean, is [the canvas set](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Canvas.html) to `Screen Space - Overlay`, `Screen Space - Camera` or `World Space`?

Comment: @Ruzihm ok, it worked in world space and Screen Space - Camera, thanks. But is there any way to make it work in Screen Space - Overlay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn your canvas's rendering mode to `Screen Space - Camera` or `World Space`.

This is necessary because render shaders (unlike compute shaders) require a camera to make any sense, and UIs made with `Screen Space - Overlay` do not make use of a camera.